# Python: breaking rules.. forgetting names..tkinter, Unicode, Utf8, Loops

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am adding this code and question at the top of my post here for ease of viewing.

x = u'\u2605' 
print(x)
y=u'\u2606'
print(y)

Print x then clear output region then print y clear output region. Repeat.

Simple. How to "play" these two strings in kivy or tkinter.

how to decode Unicode list of utf 8 sig for rendering emojis and unusual symbols in shells like idle or Jupiter notebook...

iow,

how to read a list of utf 8 sig strings which represent characters in utf 8...

i have found this answer so far

#### #

### #

```
x = u'A\u03BC\u0394\u1F52A'
print(x)

y = x.encode('utf-8')
print(y)

z = y.decode('utf-8')
print(z)
```

#### #

result:
AμΔὒA
b'A\xce\xbc\xce\x94\xe1\xbd\x92A'
AμΔὒA

### #

now rig a list counter 
in perhaps tkinter

i want to essentially flash through these characters in the unicode list, creating a very simple animation system. .i think it is a matter of selecting a set or list . and then "playing" or scrolling through the characters one at a time

((i think in some way this is where '\r' is needed))???

if this is interesting to you please offer some way of clarifying the idea

QUOTED FROM FACEBOOK GROUP WITH NO RESPONSE

Hey all, I think this would be a fun and useful python application between two android phones. Anyone knows anything about Unicode or utf 8 ... Can help me with working version of this sketch...where it plays text in place like a stop watch or time counter.. But it plays like a list of emoji basically. There is more to it if anyone is interested please comment ... Here is my sketch for this question..

```
$ import utf 8 decoder
$ import time

###display emoji from unicode - ascii

####simple .

open('file', 'w', encoding 'utf-8-sig) as f

f.write('U+2665')

f.write('U+{{{brokenheart}}}')
### then i want

clear

loop *24 times a second
```

https://unicode-table.com/en/#dingbats

comprehend ??
UNICODE-TABLE.COM

anyways im sorry i have a difficult time communicating clearly, so hope you can help ,

sincerely dante

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
u'\U00002665'
```

instead of just

```
u'U+2665'
```

note that UTF-8 needs 8 bit placements to be understood. the unicode id is 2665, but the complete id is actually 00002665. so if the id is something like 123 - then append 5 more zeroes to it: 00000123. note that: u is placed prior to the openning quote so that the string will be interpreted as a unicode.

/ogs

Comment: Thanks for your note. I had some trouble with that format. Since a lot of the character sheets list it U+0000... But I'm moving towards modifying characters and listing. In hex.